# Array of objects not being written on file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using nightmare js to fetch some data from a website and then saving it in a text file. Here's my code

```js
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = 'https://lojaonline.tim.com.br/celulares';

async function getUrls() {
    console.log('Extraindo Links...');
    const nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: false, gotoTimeout: 999999999, waitTimeout: 999999999 });
    var p1 = '51030';
    var p2 = '560';
    try {
        await nightmare.goto(url).wait('input[id="client_check_2"]')
            .click('input[id="client_check_2"]')
            .wait('input[id="zipcode"]')
            .type('input[id="zipcode"]', '51030560')
            .click('input[value="OK"]')
            .wait('.row.products-list').evaluate(function () {
                return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.offer')).map(element => element.href);
            }).end()
            .then(function (result) {
                var listaUrls = Object.values(result);
                //adicionar aqui os links com o final 'apenas-aparelho'
                var file = fs.createWriteStream('linksTim.txt', { flags: 'w', encoding: 'utf-8', mode: 0666 });
                listaUrls.forEach(function (v) {
                        file.write(v + '\r\n');
                });
                file.end();
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
};

function criarLinkApenasAparelho(link) {
    return link.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + 'apenas-aparelho' + '\r\n';
}

getUrls();
```

Inside the `evaluate` function, I read all anchor elements with the `offer` class and get their `href` attributes.

And inside the `then()` method, I save the result (the list with the `href` values) in a text file. However, the file is empty (it is modified though).

If I make a simple `console.log(listaUrls)`, it has the data. What am I doing wrong here?

Edited for more information

Comment: Can you please share the result value ? Since you have mentioned array of objects, I see you are just writing just the object ‘v’.

Comment: You need to provide more code, because that code as it is, works. So, `listaUrls` is an empty array.

Comment: *"If i check the array, it is populated."* You're not showing how you're checking or how it's populated, both of which may be part of the confusion.

Comment: Hey! I'm getting the correct result with your code!...what are you getting?? Explain a bit more...

Comment: @johnsam you are supposed to respond when people ask for more info related to your question. I really don't like when people post a question and go out for a walk or coffee

Comment: Edited for more information